# Android listviewItem border color on selected

Tags: android, listview, android-selector

I'm going to have a listview with some items, when I select a row in a listview, it should have a border. So how can I Achieve something like this.
I try this. but it works only when I press the row

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" ><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#87CEFA" />
            <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/greylight" />
            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="6dp" />

            <corners android:radius="5px" />
        </shape></item>
    <item><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/greylight" />

            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="6dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

and here is My row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backColor"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/RedColor"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use android:state_focused state in one of your items in selector

```
<item android:state_focused="true" ><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/greylight" />

        <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="6dp" />
    </shape></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code as border for your item in drawable folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#61979797" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

</shape>
```

and use this code also for selector in drawable folder  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/border" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks; but Don't work; state_selected won't work for RelativeLayout

Comment: oh sorry use android:state_pressed not selected

Comment: a.hammad ; I'm going to have a border around the Item for long time; if I use state_pressed it works only when user press the Item

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `state_selected="true"` in your selector.

Here's a something similar that I am using in one of my projects:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_selected="true">
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/White"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```